# Quadratic Binary Optimization formulation of Steiner Tree problem

Tags: graph-algorithms, optimization, tree, integer-programming

can someone point out to me a solution or give advice on how to formulate as efficiently as possible in terms of number of bits the minimum Steiner tree problem as a 0-1 quadratic optimization problem?

Edit [Context]: I am trying to find useful applications of quantum optimization (which attacks 0-1 quadratic unconstrained problems) and I thought that the minimum Steiner tree problem was a great starting point.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [scicomp.se].

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily out of scope. But I would like the OP to provide some context for why they'd want the answer to this question.

Comment: I am sorry I am not familiar with stackexchange and I thought this was the most appropriate venue. I am now about to provide context!

Comment: done! added context